# MoviePy: Concatenating video clips causes weird glitches in final video

Tags: python, ffmpeg, codec, moviepy

Is there a way to successfully always patch up any clips together in such a way that prevents weird glitches? I put together a `.mp4` from smaller `.mp4` files and I got a final video with weird glitches. I am running Python 3.6.1 on Windows 10 through Sublime Text 3. I used MoviePy to do the concatenation.

**The code:**

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips
import os.path

path = "C:/Users/blah/videos/out/"

cliparray = []

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    cliparray.append(VideoFileClip(path + filename))

final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(cliparray)

final_clip.write_videofile(path + "concatenatedvideo.mp4", codec = "libx264")
```

**The weird glitches:**

1. One of the clips turns into a 3x3 grid of smaller clips.
2. Another has the audio not lined up with the video
3. Another is sped up faster than what was normal.

Answer (score 17):

I had also glitch while concatenating different video clips. Some had different resolutions and that was making output video file with some sort of glitches. I fixed it with

```
final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(cliparray, method='compose')
```

Resulting output was without any glitch, but since they have different resolutions, the moviepy assigns highest resolution among video clips. To fix this you might just crop to same size.

Comment: I got that working from https://www.reddit.com/r/moviepy/comments/2z3q38/help_getting_glitch_art_when_concatenating_clips/

Answer (score 0):

```
from moviepy.editor import *

#load video 1 in to variable
video_1 = VideoFileClip('video1.mp4')

#load video 2 in to variable
video_2 = VideoFileClip('video2.mp4')


clips = [video_1, video_2]

# concatenating both the clips
final = concatenate_videoclips(clips,method='compose')

#writing the video into a file / saving the combined video
final.write_videofile("merged.mp4")
```